# 1: // No source code found. using truffle debug

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging

Trying to run `truffle debug <txn>` and the debugger isn't finding the source code.

```
Warning: The source code for one or more contracts could not be found.

Commands:
(enter) last command entered (step next)
(o) step over, (i) step into, (u) step out, (n) step next
(;) step instruction, (p) print instruction, (h) print this help, (q) quit
(b) toggle breakpoint, (c) continue until breakpoint
(+) add watch expression (`+:<expr>`), (-) remove watch expression (-:<expr>)
(?) list existing watch expressions
(v) print variables and values, (:) evaluate expression - see `v`

?:

1: // No source code found.
```

Truffle version:

```
Truffle v4.1.0 (core: 4.1.0)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
```

I've tried running it from the top-level directory, the test folder and the contracts folder - and each time truffle can't find the source code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is a bug: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/815

We have to be a little bit patient :)